# How to impersonate a local user

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn-server

I have a Visual SVN server setup using Windows Authentication, and I'm trying to get CruiseControl.Net to work with this, in connecting as a local user/Administrator from the build machine. Is this possible? Logging in with my own details fails;

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn" username="MYDOMAIN\wonea" password="blahblahblah">
    <trunkUrl>https://test1.mydomain.local:8443/svn//MyProj</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>E:\CCNet\Builds\</workingDirectory>   
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see which identity is running the CC.Net-Service (under control panel/Admin tools/ Services).

This account needs (read only?) svn privileges.

Then:

1. Login into the build-machine with that user-account name.
2. Run a svn.exe command.  "list" is good enough.
3. This will most likely result in the "(p)"ermanent acceptance of the certificate.

Now you can you log-out, and the automated process (the cc.net-service running under the certain identity).........will work.

Our company creates a new/separate identity for running the services, so the rights for this identity can be "tweaked up" as needed.